# ¿Como puedo comparar la salida de una funcion type() con un string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Si tengo un script en python así:

```
texto  = "TEXTO"
cadena = "<type 'str'>"
salida = type(texto)
if(cadena == salida):
    print("Es un string")
else:
    print("No es un string")
```

Creo que en teoría esta bien porque se están comparando dos strings pero siempre sale "No es un string " a pesar de que las cadenas son iguales.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Prueba con `if type(texto) == str: ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` no retorna un string, sino una instancia de la clase `type`. No puedes por tanto compararla con una cadena de forma directa.

Podrías llamar a su método `__str__` en todo caso:

```
texto  = "TEXTO"
cadena = "<class 'str'>"      # En python 3 no es "<type 'str'>"
salida = str(type(texto))
if(type(texto) == str):
    print("Es un string")
else:
    print("No es un string")
```

No obstante esta forma no es nada "pythónica" e incluso esta desaconsejada de forma explícita en PEP 8 al igual que usar el operador de igualdad de la forma `type(a) == type(b)`. Una forma mucho más simple, eficiente y legible es:

```
if type(cadena) is str:
    print("Es un string")
else:
    print("No es un string")
```

> **Advertencia:** Esto solo valida instancias de la clase `str`, no cualquier subclase de esta. En caso de querer validar también cualquier subclase se debería usar `isinstance` tal y como se recomienda en PEP 8:

```
if isinstance(texto,  str):
    print("Es un string")
else:
    print("No es un string")
```